# How to acces & modify resources in Eclipse during runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have some resources that I'm working on in an Eclipse application. I need those resources to be available for access and modification by every other plugin.

I tried to place the resources under a source folder, but that causes Eclipse to copy the resources under bin, i.e. in a jar file. Therefore I can't modify them in runtime.

My question is, where and how do I place my resources so that everyone is able to see them and the resources are available for modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

I created a fragment project which only contains my resources and nothing else. To prevent Eclipse from copying my resources to a .jar file on runtime, I added the following to the MANIFEST.MF of the fragment project:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
Bundle-ClassPath: data/,
 .
```

("data" being the folder where my resources reside.)

Thusly my resources remain as they are, and I can modify them however I want during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Workspace Mechanic plugin . It allows you to export , record and import preferences based on mechanic task files. You can have LAST MOD and RECONCILE tasks. For more information : http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the difference between the task types "Last Mod" and "Reconcile"? The page you have linked to doesn't describe these two.

Comment: I found a very brief description of Last Mod and Reconcile on [this page](https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wikis/PreferenceTasks.wiki).

Comment: "_A LASTMOD task imports preferences if they have never been imported before, and when they are modified on disk. This is useful for publishing broad preferences for large groups of people. When changes are made, individuals will have a chance to import the new preferences.
...
A little implementation detail: The Workspace Mechanic takes different approaches when LASTMOD tasks are specified via disk or URL. The last modification time of file-based LASTMOD are used to compute difference, and MD5-hash values are used for URL-based LASTMOD tasks._"

Comment: "_A RECONCILE task verifies that each preference in your running Eclipse instance matches the values it contains. If any values do not match the task fails and the user will be allowed to fix the mismatched preferences.
...
This type of task is useful for overriding global preferences specified in a LASTMOD preference task._"